# Question on quotient space

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

I was recently given this product space $X\times [0,1]$ with equivalence relation generated by $(x, 1) ~(y, 1)$.  How to show the quotient space is connected? I just cannot do it Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually path connected: Every elements in this quotient space are connected to $[X \times \{1\}]$ (This is a point in the quotient). To show this, just think of how every $(x, t) \in X\times [0,1]$ are connected to $(x, 1)$).

As path connected space is connected, you are done.

Comment: how exactly are they connected?

Comment: Think of a space so that for points are connected to a fixed point $z$, then any two points $x, y$ are connected: First connect $x \to z$ then $z\to y$. (Is that your question? or are you asking how $(x, t)$ is connected to $(x, 1)$?

Comment: yes how to connect points specofically

Comment: to the point with 1 i mean

Comment: In the interval $[0, 1]$, how do you connected a $t\in [0,1]$ to $1$? @zbigniew2015

Comment: ok got it thanks